# Estimation of $\|V\|_2$ from it's columns

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

given $ V \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ Matrix with columns $v_i$

Show that if $\| v_i \|_2 \lt C, \forall i $ then $\| V \|_2 \lt \sqrt nC$

Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz

I tried it via $\| V \|_2 \le c \| V \|_1 $ equivalence of norms. But I dont see a way to relate the matrix norm to its columns.

Greetings.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652414/l2-matrix-norm-upper-bound-in-terms-of-bounds-of-its-column?rq=1  And you have to argue for yourself that $\|V\|_2=\|V^T\|_2$

Comment: Thank you. Should I delete or something?